# CSS: confused over some simple math

Tags: css

I have the following CSS at [this page](http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test/):

```
#left {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2.5%;
}
#right {
  display: table-cell;
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
}
```

I believe that 2.5 + 20 + 2.5 + 75 = 100.

However, there is a large gap between `#left` and `#right`.  Why is that there?  I thought `#left` and `#right` would take up all of `#main`.

Also, how do I reset the `#footer`, so it lines up underneath `#left`?

Thank you.

Comment: You should not float table cells, actually if you get rid of the float that might be the solution. EDIT: also it would be nice if you could add some html to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using box-sizing: border-box; as the part of reset css. Just comment/remove that and try again.

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

Also recommended to use the structure like below for fix the footer issue.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Jaison.  Do you know how I line up #footer with #left?

Comment: Just move the #footer at the end of #right and add a additional div wrap for #left and #right.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `box-sizing` attribute which is confusing you - this causes padding to use up the space inside the element rather than stretching the element, which is how browsers generally behave. So by having the box-sizing attribute and width: 20%, the browser will only ever draw this element at 20% width rather than adding an extra 2.5% either side.

If you make the width 25% and keep the box-sizing, it'll behave as you're expecting.

Here's [a good explanation of box-sizing by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) which should explain what's going on (and [another from CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)).

Answer (score 1):

Padding not added to the width because you have 'box-sizing:border-box' on all elements. Read about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```